# Delphi- Is it possible to style a firemonkey TOpenDialog?

Tags: delphi, styles, firemonkey

Is it possible to style a firemonkey TOpenDialog?
If so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hey @Vladimir, please try to add some more details to your post of what exactly you are asking. You can add the code that you have already tried (if any), or any screenshots/examples that would be helpful to those knowledgable with Delphi.

Comment: @cet51: Hi, I placed a TOpenDialog component on a data module and I don't know how to style it from there...I'm not sure how to make my question have more detailed other than that. All the material I've read so far don't explain how to do this...so I wondered if this is possible.

Comment: @ Tom Brunberg: Hi, I'm using Tokyo 10.2.3. Thanks for the link...can you use this with firemonkey?

Comment: No, the link @TomBrunberg provided is not for FMX. It's only for VCL.

Comment: There's a StyleName property for TOpenDialog. Does it not work for you?

Comment: Sorry Vladimir, I made a mistake.

Comment: @ Tom Brunberg: No worries Tom...

Comment: @Ken White: Has this worked for you before? I've look at the StyleName property but with no real idea what to point it at as the styles don't seem to include system dialogs...